# Extract predefined names in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have an information column. I need to check the content of each cell to see which user account sent that information. The text in each cell usually contains the name of the user but it has no set format.

I have the list of all usernames (named range "Accounts").

Our plan to extract the username in each cell is to use a custom Excel VBA function to:

1. Find Min and Max of text length of all usernames (to minimize the lengths of extracted text to check)
2. Loop through the cell content to extract it into various extracted texts of different extract length)
3. Compare various extracted texts (from cell content) by using Vlookup with list of username
4. If the extracted texts in a cell match with usernames, save them into a value
5. If there are multiple matched texts in a cell, still save them into a value and separate them by special character ("/")

The function shows an error.

```
Function EXTRACTNICK(MinLen As Integer, MaxLen As Integer, checktext As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim textLen As Integer
Dim extractText As String
Dim Str As String

Str = ""

    For textLen = MinLen To MaxLen
        For i = 1 To (Len(checktext) - textLen + 1)
            extractText = Mid(checktext, i, textLen)
            If IsError(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(extractText, Range("Accounts"), 1, False)) Then
                Str = Str
            Else
                Str = Str & " / " & extractText
            End If
        Next i
    Next textLen

ExtractNickName = Str

End Function
```

Comment: @urdearboy Please download the find from here https://www.mediafire.com/file/4ub0wumn3st3s0d/Example.xlsm/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the photo, assume my yellow range is equal to your named range `Accounts`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Extracting(name As Range) As String

Dim Arr, i As Long
Arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    If InStr(name, Arr(i, 1), 0) Then
        Extracting = Extracting & Arr(i, 1) & "/"
    End If
Next i

If Extracting = "" Then
    Extracting = "No Users Found"
Else
    Extracting = Left(Extracting, Len(Extracting) - 1)
End If

End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your solution works fine for me. However, some usernames have uppercase letters so is there any other way for InStr to work for binary comparison?

Comment: We don’t do this for free! Give credit where credit is due. (Hit check mark ✅)